# SpringBoot REST - Insert Row With Foreign Key using HTTP POST JSON Data

Tags: javascript, java, json, hibernate, spring-boot

all.

I'm having trouble figuring out a simple problem. I have two entities in a Spring Boot application. It has a web RESTful interface. I can insert and select rows that are independent of other tables just fine, but I cannot correctly insert a row that has a foreign key. The row inserts but without the ID to link it to the parent table.

Parent table Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String firstname;
private String mi;
private String lastname;

...}
```

Child table Invoice:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE")
public class Invoice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private Date dropoff;
private Date ready;
private String note;
private Boolean paid;
private BigDecimal total_price;
private long total_quantity;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
private Customer customer;

...}
```

Here's the POST tests I've tried to send to http://localhost:8080/invoices

POST Test 1:
    `{
        "dropoff":"2017-01-30 10:33",
        "ready":"",
        "paid":"false",
        "note":"manual insert",
        "customer_id":"1"
    }`

POST Test 2:
    `{
        "dropoff":"2017-01-30 10:33",
        "ready":"",
        "paid":"false",
        "note":"manual insert",
        "customer":{
          "id":"1"
        }
    }`

POST Test 3:
    `{
        "dropoff":"2017-01-30 10:33",
        "ready":"",
        "paid":"false",
        "note":"manual insert",
        "customerid":"1"
    }`

POST Test 4:
    `{
        "dropoff":"2017-01-30 10:33",
        "ready":"",
        "paid":"false",
        "note":"manual insert",
        "customerId":"1"
    }`

When I run select on the table Invoice I see the data, but it is not associated with customer id of 1.

Interesting result: When I try **POST example 2** above, it updates invoice the invoice record with id = 1. Appears to ignore the object customer inside the post package.

Not sure what format I need to follow to get invoice to be tied to customer id of 1. So far all of them insert, but without any foreign key to table Customer

Comment: Your spring is specting the whole object of customer, you could try sending it complete or changing your mapping to lazy so you don't have to send an object in customer and just its id. Btw this is an issue of Hibernate mapping.

Comment: thanks, I tried but same result. Mapping has always been set to lazy. Oops, nevermind that last part about lazy. Obviously it is set to eager in the example above..

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the URL to the object like:

```
  "account" : "http://example.com/accounts/9999"
```

in your case, you'd replace "account" with "customer"

Answer (score 1):

```
POST Test 2:  {
        "dropoff":"2017-01-30 10:33",
        "ready":"",
        "paid":"false",
        "note":"manual insert",
        "customer":{
          "id":"1"
        }
    }
```

Test 2 is perfect but if you not sending id of customer it will automatically generate because you are using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

You have to create a **InvoiceRepository.java** for getting invoice with customer id like below code.

```
@Repository
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Serializable>{
    Invoice findByCustomerId(long id);
}
```

This will return you invoice with a particular customer id.